# Why I can't lein install this project using `deps.edn`, lein plugin (lein-tools-deps), and maven packages hosted on GitHub Package?

Tags: maven, authentication, clojure, leiningen, github-package-registry

I am trying to enhance the dependency management of a Clojure/ClojureScript project built with `lein`. Hence, I am using a library called [lein-tools-deps](https://github.com/RickMoynihan/lein-tools-deps). I added it to my `project.clj` file:

```clj
(defproject my-project
  :description "description"
  :url "https://github.com/pdelfino/whatever-does-the-repos-name-matter-at-all-here?"

  :plugins [[lein-tools-deps "0.4.5"]]

  ...omitted...)
```

The main purpose of this addition is getting *private* maven packages directly from GitHub Packages instead of having them locally and doing `lein install` for every new release.

Also, I created a `deps.edn` file. It works for the `public packages`. But, I am having trouble with the `private` ones. I am trying to follow the [documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli#_dependencies). Hence, I tried:

```clj
{:paths ["src" "dev"]

 :deps { ;; lein dependencies
        org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.9.0"}
        org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.339"}
        org.clojure/tools.nrepl {:mvn/version "RELEASE"}
   
        ;; private
        com.my-organization/private-repo1 {:mvn/version "1.2.15"
                                            :deps/manifest :pom
                                            :git/url "https://github.com/my-org/private-repo"} 

        com.my-organization/private-repo2 {:sha "230483c88ff1cef5248878182ec98cff07b212a9"
                                          ;:git/tag "v1.2.15"
                                           :git/url "git@github.com:my-org/private-repo.git"}}
                               
                               
  :mvn/repos {"github" {:url "https://maven.pkg.github.com/my_organization/*"}

             ;; "github-2" {:url "https://github.com/my_organization/*"}}}
```

The private packages are being hosted on GitHub Packages as private packages:

There is a XML holding meta-data:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my-organization</groupId>
  <artifactId>private-repo1</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

In addition, I have a `.m2/settings.xml` file:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository/>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <servers>
      <!-- <server> -->
      <!--    <id>github-2</id> -->
      <!--    <username>pdelfino</username> -->
      <!--    <password>my-password-which-will-not-be-shared</password> -->
      <!--    <configuration> -->
      <!--        <httpHeaders> -->
      <!--            <property> -->
      <!--                <name>Authorization</name> -->
      <!--                <!-\- Base64-encoded "<username>:<password>" -\-> -->
      <!--                <value>Basic password-which-will-not-be-shared==</value> -->
      <!--            </property> -->
      <!--        </httpHeaders> -->
      <!--    </configuration> -->
      <!-- </server> -->
      <server>
         <id>github</id>
         <username>pdelfino</username>
         <password>password-which-will-not-be-shared</password>
         <configuration>
             <httpHeaders>
                 <property>
                     <name>Authorization</name>
                     <!-- Base64-encoded "<username>:<password>" -->
                     <value>Basic converted-password-which-will-not-be-shared==</value>
                 </property>
             </httpHeaders>
         </configuration>
       </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors/>
    <proxies/>
    <profiles/>
    <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Unfortunately, when I execute `lein install` on this repository, my
expectation was that the packages would be successfully installed.

But, terminal returns an error:

```bash
➜  lein install
If there are a lot of uncached dependencies this might take a while ...
Cloning: git@github.com:my-organization/private-repo1.git
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:my-organization/private-repo1.git: Auth fail
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. But, I do not fully understand my own solution.

First, I kept the `.m2/settings.xml`. But it does **not** hold my
credentials anymore:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
      <server>
         <id>github</id>
         <username></username>
         <password></password>
       </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Also, on `project.clj` I added:

```clj
  :repositories {"releases"  {:url           "https://maven.pkg.github.com/tallyfor/*"
                              :username      "pdelfino"
                              :password      :env}}
```

Note that the `:password` has a pointer `:env` making a reference to
the environment which I have configured via an edition of `.zshrc`:

```clj
export LEIN_PASSWORD="my-personal-access-github-token-which-will-not-be-shared"
```

Note that the string
"my-personal-access-github-token-which-will-not-be-shared" is the same
I have on my `.npmrc` file to install private npm packages being
hosted for free on GitHub.

One of the points that I do not understand is why a need to keep the
`.m2/settings.xml` even though it does **not** have any content.

If I comment out the content on `.m2/settings.xml`:

```xml
<!-- <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" -->
<!--       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"> -->
<!--     <servers> -->
<!--       <server> -->
<!--          <id>github</id> -->
<!--          <username></username> -->
<!--          <password></password> -->
<!--        </server> -->
<!--     </servers> -->
<!-- </settings> -->
```

And if I try to execute `lein install` again, it *does not* work:

```bash
➜  LEIN_SNAPSHOTS_IN_RELEASE=true lein install
If there are a lot of uncached dependencies this might take a while ...
java.io.IOException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /Users/pedro/.m2/settings.xml: no more data available START_DOCUMENT seen ...<!-- </settings> -->\n... @11:1 @ /Users/pedro/.m2/settings.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need the plugin. As long as you can access the repository via SSH from the machine where you are running the build on (otherwise [configure `ssh-agent`](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli#_coord_attributes)), you can add the dependency to `deps.edn` with the `ssh` link:

```clj
com.my-organization/private-repo1 
{:git/url "ssh://git@github.com:/my-org/private-repo.git"
 :sha "230483c88ff1cef5248878182ec98cff07b212a9"}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried your suggestion, but I still get: "org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://github.com/tallyfor/balance-shared: Auth fail". Using SSH, I can git clone and push changes to repositories. For some reason, I can't do the trick you suggested.

Comment: Also, does your approach create the necessity for local execution of the command `lein install`?