# In Leiningen configuration, how can I use environment variables to export the username?

Tags: clojure, environment-variables, leiningen

This question is related to this [previous
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74115124/why-i-cant-lein-install-this-project-using-deps-edn-lein-plugin-lein-tools).

I am able to install private Maven packages available on GitHub
packages with the following setting on `project.clj`:

```clj
...

  :repositories {"releases"  {:url           "https://maven.pkg.github.com/my-organization-name/*"
                              :username      "pdelfino"
                              :password      :env}}

...
```

As you see, I can already use `environment-variables` for the
password, since it was set on my `.zshrc` file:

```
export LEIN_PASSWORD="my-personal-access-token-which-will-not-be-shared"
```

I would like to do the same for the username! This would be particularly important since other folks are working on this project.

I tried a few things, but none of them worked out. One example of documentation only illustrates how to do it with the password (using `LEIN_PASSWORD` - [see here](https://codeberg.org/leiningen/leiningen/src/commit/3d3570b4e76fbafedff8788faa79e54a45625863/sample.project.clj#L130)) but **does not** solve the username part. Executing `lein help sample` generates the same content previously mentioned.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `:env/thenameofthevar` should do it?  See https://codeberg.org/leiningen/leiningen/src/branch/main/doc/DEPLOY.md#credentials-in-the-environment

Comment: Indeed, it worked out. I tried that earlier today. The problem was probably that it was necessary to refresh iTerm2 after tweaking `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181392/cfrick) in a comment, the solution was adding the snippet below on my `.zshrc` file, use the pointer on `project.clj`, **and** re-starting the terminal:

```clj
  :repositories {"releases"  {:url           "https://maven.pkg.github.com/tallyfor/*"
                              :username      :env/LEIN_USERNAME 
                              :password      :env/LEIN_PASSWORD}}
```

```
export LEIN_USERNAME="pdelfino"
export LEIN_PASSWORD="my-personal-access-token-which-will-not-be-shared"
```

I tried that earlier today. But, forgot to re-start the terminal (iTerm2).

Comment: Not really related to the problem, but just to mention it: you can
`source` your `.zshrc` instead to read the exports afresh.